# How can I concatenate two integers in Python?

Tags: python, concatenation

How do I concatenate two integer numbers in Python? For example, given `10` and `20`, I'd like a returned value of `1020`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this in python was given in the accepted answer - but if you want to do this in jinja2 templates - the concatenation operator `~` gives you a neat way of doing this since it looks for the unicode representation of all objects, thus, you can 'concatenate integers' as well.

That is you can do this (given `a=10` and `b=20`):

```
{{ a ~ b }}
```

Answer (score 70):

Cast both to a string, concatenate the strings and then cast the result back to an integer:

```
z = int(str(x) + str(y))
```

Answer (score 19):

Using math is probably faster than solutions that convert to str and back:

If you can assume a two digit second number:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x*100+y
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(1,2)
102
>>> f(10,20)
1020
```

Although, you probably would want some checks included to verify the second number is not more than two digits. Or, if your second number can be any number of digits, you could do something like this:

```
import math
def f(x, y):
    if y != 0:
        a = math.floor(math.log10(y))
    else:
        a = -1

    return int(x*10**(1+a)+y)
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(10,20)
1020
>>> f(99,193)
99193
```

This version however, does not allow you to merge numbers like 03 and 02 to get 0302. For that you would need to either add arguments to specify the number of digits in each integer, or use strings.

Comment: don't you think importing math would slow things down?

Comment: @gokcehan Yes, but if you were to call this function many times in a loop then the time to import math would be insignificant

Comment: Also, it makes more sense mathematically than string manipulation.

Comment: Why not use `ceil` instead of using `floor` and adding one?

Comment: @mbomb007 `ceil(num) != floor(num) + 1` for all `num`. Specifically, if `num` is an integer, then `ceil(num) == floor(num)`. If you replaced `floor()+1` with `ceil()` the function would not work properly when the second argument was an integer power of 10. (Since `log10(10^n) = n` you are in a case where `floor(n) == ceil(n)`)

Comment: Yeah, I remember. Thanks.

Comment: This is not the problem requested. for example, it would not work if you try to concatenate 10 and 200, it would result in 1200 instead of 10200. you could use `def f(x, y):  return x*10**len(str(y))+y` but I still think this isn't the point, as it seems the requester expected a string in output. it's a common problem in python to not be able to concatenate number.

Comment: @Rafiki The OP requested to merge "two integer numbers", which at the time I interpreted to mean "two numbers of two digits each". This may not be what was intended, but I feel that the OP should have brought up the misunderstanding sooner, if this was not what was desired. This approach can be easily expanded to work more generally, if you have additional information about the numbers. Finally, strings containing numbers are not numbers. If strings were required/desired, it should have been stated.

Comment: Using Math converter is faster than converting to string and back in my testing:
```
In [28]: fn = lambda x, y: x*100 + y                                                                               

In [29]: timeit fn(1,2)                                                                                            
88.4 ns ± 1.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [30]: timeit int(str(1) + str(2))                                                                               
427 ns ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Example 1: (*Example 2 is much faster, don't say I didn't warn you!*)**

```
a = 9
b = 8
def concat(a, b):
    return eval(f"{a}{b}")
```

Example:

```
>>> concat(a, b)
98
```

**Example 2:**

For people who think `eval` is 'evil', here's another way to do it:

```
a = 6
b = 7
def concat(a, b):
    return int(f"{a}{b}")
```

Example:

```
>>> concat(a, b)
67
```

**EDIT:**

I thought it would be convienient to time these codes, look below:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat("for x in range(100): int(str(a) + str(b))", "",
          number=100000, globals = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
9.107237317533617
>>> min(timeit.repeat("for x in range(100): int(f'{a}{b}')", "",
          number=100000, globals = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
6.4986298607643675
>>> min(timeit.repeat("for x in range(5): eval(f'{a}{b}')", "", #notice the range(5) instead of the range(100)
          number=100000, globals = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
4.089137231865948 #x20
```

The times:

```
eval: about 1 minute and 21 seconds.

original answer: about 9 seconds.

my answer: about 6 and a half seconds.
```

**Conclusion:**

> **The *original answer* does look more *readable*, but if you need a *good speed*, choose *int(f'{vara}{varb}')***

**P.S: My int(f'{a}{b}) syntax *only works on python 3.6+, as the f'' syntax is undefined at python versions 3.6-***

Answer (score 5):

using old-style string formatting:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 20
>>> z = int('%d%d' % (x, y))
>>> print z
1020
```

Answer (score 4):

A rough but working implementation:

```
i1,i2 = 10,20
num = int('%i%i' % (i1,i2))
```

Basically, you just merge two numbers into one string and then cast that back to int.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the 'correct' answer would be Konstantin's answer. But if you still want to know how to do it without using string casts, just with math:

```
import math

def numcat(a,b):
    return int(math.pow(10,(int(math.log(b,10)) + 1)) * a + b)

>> numcat(10, 20)
>> 1020
```

Comment: Won't work concatenating 0 like`lastnum=3` as `numcat(lastnum,0)` ValueError: math domain error

Answer (score 2):

Just to give another solution:

```
def concat_ints(a, b):
    return a*(10**len(str(b)))+b

>>> concat_ints(10, 20)
1020
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this function you can concatenate as many numbers as you want

```
def concat(*args):
    string = ''
    for each in args:
        string += str(each) 
    return int(string)
```

For example `concat(20, 10, 30)` will return `201030` an an integer

**OR**

You can use the one line program

```
int(''.join(str(x) for x in (20,10,30)))
```

This will also return `201030`.

Comment: or just do: `concat = lambda *args: int("".join(map(str, args)))`, it is faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
a = 10
b = 20

x = int('{}{}'.format(a, b))
```

Comment: Thats the best way for my opinion

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate a list of integers

```
int(''.join(map(str, my_list)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Math converter is faster than converting to string and back in my testing:

```
In [28]: fn = lambda x, y: x*10 + y                                                                               

In [29]: timeit fn(1,2)                                                                                            
88.4 ns ± 1.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [30]: timeit int(str(1) + str(2))                                                                               
427 ns ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: `int(str(1) + str(2)) == fn(1,2)` => `False`

Comment: @kafran I think I had an extra zero in there. I meant x*10 not x*100. Corrected it. My response was to a previous comment about speed of execution. In my observation it is slower going to string and back. Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree. For me this is the best way to concat two int.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way as well would be to use the built-in reduce() function:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x*10+y,[10,20])
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add a generalized formula for any number of digits:

```
import math
from functools import reduce


def f(*args):
    def numcat(a, b):
        return int(math.pow(10, (round(math.log(b, 10)) + 1)) * a + b)
    return reduce(numcat, args)


c = f(10, 1, 2, 1000, 3)  # 101210003
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast both the integer values to string, add them and convert them again into integer:

```
x, y = str(10), str(20)

z = int(x + y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
`print(f"{10}" + f"{20}")`
It should work!!

Answer (score 0):

Taking 2 variable inputs you can do:

```py
value1 = 10
value2 = 20
concatenated = int(f"{value1}{value2}")
print(concatenated)
```

Comment: This seems to duplicate what at least two other answers have already suggested (the only difference is you're using different syntax).

Answer (score -1):

```
def concatenate_int(x, y):

  try:
     a = floor(log10(y))
  except ValueError:
     a = 0
  return int(x * 10 ** (1 + a) + y)


def concatenate(*l):
  j = 0
  for i in list(*l):
     j = concatenate_int(j, i)
  return j
```

Comment: It would be good if you also would write some explaination to your code.

Comment: ***Hmm. -1: your `concatenate_int` function look suspiciously like @Matt 's answer.***