# Sending multiple values via sockets with Python to Pure Data

Tags: python, sockets, puredata

I'm using this code to send information to Pure Data, in the Python console I see the two different variables, however Pure Data keeps receiving them added together not as two separate numbers.

```
import bge

# run main program
main()

import socket

# get controller 
cont2 = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
# get object that controller is attached to 
owner2 = cont2.owner
# get the current scene 
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# get a list of the objects in the scene 
objList = scene.objects

# get object named Box 
enemy = objList["enemy"]
enemy2 = objList["enemy2"]

# get the distance between them 
distance = owner2.getDistanceTo(enemy)
XValue = distance  
print (distance)
# get the distance between them 
distance2 = owner2.getDistanceTo(enemy2)
XValue = distance2  
print (distance2)    

tsr = str(distance + distance2)     
tsr += ';'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 50007
msg = '123456;'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(tsr.encode())
s.shutdown(0)
s.close()
```

I need to send up to 10 different distances from objects, this is to do with finding distances from enemies

Comment: please try to trim down your problem to a *minimal* example. e.g. it's rather irrelevant that you query `bge` to get your `enemies`, and what's that `msg` and `XValue` assignments doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838549/how-to-concatenate-two-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is entirely in your python code:

You have two variables `distance1` and `distance2` (let's assume that `distance1=666` and `distance2=42` and then you construct a string:

```
tsr = str(distance1 + distance2)
```

Now this will first evaluate the expression `distance1+distance2` (summing them up to `708`) and then create a string from that value (`"708"`).
So your Python script sends the munged data.

So your first step is to convert your values to *strings* before "adding" them (since *adding* strings is really *appending* them):

```
tsr = str(distance1) + str(distance2)
```

But this will really give you a string `"66642"`, as you haven't told the appender to separate the to values with a whitespace.

So one correct solution is:

```
tsr = str(distance1) + " " + str(distance2)
tsr += ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1="5Hello3How3Are3you8I'm FINE2is4that3so?3yes"
#initial measurement

m=var1[0]
m=int(m)
print var1[1:1+m]
INIT_LEN=1
LENGTH=m
n=1
NUMBER_FRAMES=9-1 #number of bytes 9

while n<=NUMBER_FRAMES:
  INIT_LEN=INIT_LEN+LENGTH
  l=var1[INIT_LEN]
  INIT_LEN=INIT_LEN+1
  LENGTH=int(l)
  print var1[INIT_LEN:INIT_LEN+LENGTH]
  n=n+1
```

If youre willing to transfer multiple strings concatinated as single concatinated string I suggest you go through the current code.