# Numbers Only, Rounding up, and adding

Tags: python-3.x

so I am still learning Python so this should be rather easy to answer for some of you experts...

1) How can you make it so only numbers are accepted as an input?

```
def check_only_digit():
    digits = input("Please input a number ")
    if digits in "0123456789":
        print("Working")
    else:
        print("Not working")

check_only_digit()
```

This will print "Working" if the inputted is a number in 0123456789 but only is this order. What I am asking is there any way to make it in any order?

2) How can I make the users digit round UP to the nearest 10?

```
def round_up():
    users_number = input("Please input a number you want rounded ")
    answer = round(int(users_number), -1)
    print (answer)

round_up()
```

3) Is there anyway to add a number onto the end of another number? For example for 1+1, instead of equaling 2, can it equal 11?

I would like to thank you all for your responses in advance.

Comment: Question 1 is a duplicate of [How can I limit the user input to only integers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326099/how-can-i-limit-the-user-input-to-only-integers-in-python).

Comment: Question 2 is an exact duplicate of [Python - round up to the nearest ten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454649/python-round-up-to-the-nearest-ten).

Comment: Question 3 is a duplicate of [Merge two integers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838549/merge-two-integers-in-python).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand them answers. I would much prefer it if someone could help me with my examples.

Comment: Also the second one I need to the nearest ten. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

For Answer 1:

```
    def check_Numbers():
         number=input("Enter a number: ")
         try:
              number=int(number)
              print("Working")
         except(ValueError):
              print("Not Working")
```

For Answer 2:

```
    def rounding_Off():
        userNumber=float(input("Enter a floating point number to round off: "))
        roundedOff=round(userNumber,-1)
        return roundedOff
```

For Answer 3:

```
    def addNumbers():
         number1=input("Enter one number: ")
         number2=input("Enter another one: ")

         newNumber=number1+number2
         return int(newNumber)
         #return newNumber <----- This if you want to get your number in string format.
```

Comment: Hi thanks, Answer 2 does not round up to nearest 10?

Comment: Ohh my bad, i misread the question as to round it off to nearest integer.

Comment: Now Edited the comment..If this helped you, please upvote the answer. :)