# How to combine numbers?

Tags: python, variables

```
x = 5
y = 8
```

I want to combine those variables and define an another variable, like:

```
z = 58
```

Comment: Have you ttried something (do you remember doing math problems)?

Comment: `combine` as in `z=10*x+y`?

Comment: What's the expected result if `x=10` and `y=3`? 103? 13?

Comment: @Aran-Fey both "most plausible" combination methods would give `103` here. Much more interesting would have been the question what happens if `x = 3` and `y = 10`: is it then `310` or `40`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yeah, you're right. I should've thought a bit longer about the numbers I used...

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838549/merge-two-integers-in-python) for other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "combine".

You can concatenate numbers as strings:

```
z = int(str(x) + str(y))
```

But you can also compute `x * 10 + y`:

```
z = x * 10 + y
```

This will give different results if `y > 9`, e.g. for `x = 5` and `y = 10`, the first version will give `510`, while the second version will give `60`.

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to strings and concatenate them, then convert them back to an integer:

```
z = int(str(x) + str(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.6 or later, this can be done quite concisely with *[format strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)*:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 8
>>> z = int(f'{x}{y}')
>>> z
58
>>>
```

A more general solution would be something like:

```
>>> def join_ints(*args):
...     return int(''.join(map(str, args)))
... 
>>> join_ints(5, 6, 8, 3)
5683
>>>
```